# Php calling of property like this, bad practice?

Tags: php, oop, class, object, properties

I'm wondering if doing this is considered bad practice?

```
class myClass
{
    public static $someVars;

    public static function setVars()
    {
        self::$someVars = new stdClass;
        self::$someVars->var1 = 'Some Text';
        self::$someVars->var2 = 'something Else';
        self::$someVars->var3 = 'Different Content Here';
    }
    public static function getVar()
    {
        return self::$someVars;
    }
}
myClass::setVars();
echo myClass::getVar()->var1;
```

I've been trying to find something about this way to access the $someVars property, but without luck, which leads me to believe it could be bad practice.

Further, using the same setup I can update the property like this:

```
myClass::getVar()->var1 = 'New Texts, WOOT!';
echo myClass::getVar()->var1;
```

Again, acceptable or bad practice?

And whats it called doing accessing the property/object like this? I've been googling for over an hour but been unable to find anything about it, maybe due to not knowing exactly what to search for, or maybe because its a nasty way to do business ;)

Thanks for your help and helping me learn!

Comment: Such constructs smell anyway as it seems like you are building some kind of registry pattern implementation. Could you present the intention of the code? This might improve the quality of the answers ;)

Comment: Please explain why everything is static?

Comment: @MarioMueller How come you think this construct smells? I don't question it, I just want to understand why you think so. I'm thinking of storing some settings that would remain unchanged throughout the site, so I'm thinking this might a good(?) way of doing it?

Comment: @EdHeal I'm setting everything static so that I can access it (the settings) from any class without passing it along or use globals.

Comment: @Jay Static (and therefore global) class constructs are in theory the same as using globals. This all depends on what kind of software you write. I you need to maintain it for a longer period, I would recommend looking at Dependency Injection and creating a configuration class of which you can pass around an instance. If you just need a short shot for something you throw away next week, this kind-of-registry will be enough to pass things around.